# Broken constraints when using ToolBarItemGroup to add additional button above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {

    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var keyboardFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Add text here", text: $text)
                        .focused($keyboardFocused)

                }
            }
        }.toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    keyboardFocused = false
                }, label: {
                    Text("Done")
                })

            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FormView()
}
```

So its just adds one `Done` button above keyboard. I use `Spacer` to push it to the right.

But all this give me this warning in console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
> of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
> this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
> don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
> or constraints and fix it.    (Note: If you're seeing
> NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
> to the documentation for the UIView property
> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x282c9f8e0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x103e23ec0.width == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c8ba20 H:|-(16)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x103e242e0]   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x103e23ec0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c8b9d0 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x103e242e0]-(16)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x103e23ec0 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x282c8b9d0
> H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x103e242e0]-(16)-|   (active, names:
> '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x103e23ec0 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
> to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
> UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
> <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Same happens even without a `Spacer` when I just leave button in the middle. This is the whole code and I can reproduce the warning with it. I am using XCode version 15.3 (15E204a)

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SwiftUI adds conflicting constraints all the time. I'd say just don't worry about it. This is SwiftUI's fault.

Comment: Hm, ok thanks. I was hoping its not an actual problem @Sweeper